# Matplotlib center align y tick labels

Tags: matplotlib

[image]

I have created the above plot using Matplot lib.
I would like to know how to centre align the y-tick labels (if it is possible).
I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
for tick in ax[1].yaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    tick.set_horizontalalignment("center")
```

Many thanks, your help is appreciated

Current code below:

```
#create plotting space
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,5),ncols=2)
fig.tight_layout()

#left plot
ax[0].barh(df_word_comp.index, df_word_comp.negative, align='center',color = '#d55e00')
ax[0].set_title('Negative Reviews',fontsize=14)
ax[0].invert_xaxis()
ax[0].invert_yaxis()
ax[0].yaxis.tick_right()
ax[0].yaxis.set_ticklabels([])

 

#right plot
ax[1].barh(df_word_comp.index, df_word_comp.positive, align='center',color = '#0072b2')
ax[1].set_title('Positive Reviews',fontsize=14)
ax[1].invert_yaxis()
ax[1].yaxis.tick_left()
ax[1].tick_params(axis='y',labelsize=13)


plt.suptitle('Word Frequency',y=0,fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.16);
```

Comment: I did a lot of research and could only find a way to add a pad or annotate with text. Perhaps the best answer is, how about inserting spaces before and after the label on the right x-axis with string processing? `ax[1].barh([x.center(12) for x in df_word_comp.name],...)`

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks for trying, appreciate the effort. I managed to find a solution. Posted below if you are interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I managed this  using axisartist from mpl_toolkits.
https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/gallery/axisartist/demo_ticklabel_alignment.html

Full code below but the key line is `ax2.axis["left"].major_ticklabels.set_ha("center")`

Not perfect code, so if anyone sees how I could improve, please let me know

```
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as axisartist

#set figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))

#left plot
ax1=fig.add_subplot(121, axes_class = axisartist.Axes)
ax1.barh(df_word_comp.index, df_word_comp.negative, color = '#d55e00')
ax1.set_title('Negative Reviews',fontsize=14)
ax1.invert_yaxis()
ax1.invert_xaxis()
ax1.axis["left",'top'].toggle(all=False)
ax1.yaxis.set_ticklabels([])

#right plot
ax2=fig.add_subplot(122, axes_class = axisartist.Axes,)
ax2.barh(df_word_comp.index, df_word_comp.positive, color = '#0072b2')
ax2.set_title('Positive Reviews', fontsize=14)
ax2.axis["left"].major_ticklabels.set_ha("center")
ax2.axis["left"].major_ticklabels.set_fontsize(14)
ax2.axis["right",'top'].toggle(all=False)
ax2.invert_yaxis()


# plt.suptitle
plt.figtext(0.465,0.95,'Word Frequency',fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.17);
```